# Why I am getting this error on my Jupyter Notebook and not on online Jupyter?

Tags: pandas

```
a = customers.merge(c, left_on="Customers NIC", right_index=True)
a.columns = ['Customers NIC', 'Customer Name', 'Tr counts']
```

[image]

Comment: What error? I dont see any.

Comment: Please check the image attached

Comment: `c` is a Series. replace it with `c.to_frame()`.

Comment: Why the same code works fine on online jupyter?

Comment: Different version of pandas. I believe new version allows merge with (named) series. That said, you **should** mention what you just said in the original question.

Comment: Thanks with c.to_frame() it worked

Comment: What is online Jupyter?

Comment: Its the online version of Jupyter Notebook that you can use remotely